# Integration Method, hit and miss in R

Tags: r, algorithm, simulation, montecarlo

I want to calculate the following integrate by using the hit and miss method.
`I=∫x^3dx` with `lower= 0` and `upper =1`

I know how to solve it but I cannot find the right code in `R` to calculate it and generate -for example 100000 random- and then plot them like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0CmK.png]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**1.** Generate 2 vectors from uniform distribution of the desired length

```
l = 10000
x = runif(l)
y = runif(l)
```

**2.** The approximation of the integral is the number of cases where the (x,y) points are below the function you want to integrate:

```
sum(y<x^3)/l
```

**3.** For the plot, you just have to plot the points, changing their color depending whether they are above or below the curve, and add the function with `curve()`:

```
plot(x,y,col=1+(y<x^3))
curve(x^3,add=T,col=3)
```

Comment: do you know maybe how i can calculate the same function using antithetic variates?

Comment: no, but see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183453/calculating-integral-with-antithetic-variables/183920#183920